# How to mock forEach behavior using Mock

Tags: cucumber, bdd, junit5

I am new for Junits with BDD and i am trying to mock below forEach behavior but i am getting null pointer exception .Can some one help me to implement BDD for below scenario.

### book.feature

```
Feature: Test CURD Methods in BOOKSTORE

  Scenario: Verify all books
    Given Execute Book Details
    When I Set book request
    Then I receive valid Response
```

### BooksService

```
@Service
public class BooksService {
    @Autowired
    BooksRepository booksRepository;
    public List<Books> getAllBooks() {
        List<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>();
        booksRepository.findAll().forEach(books1 -> books.add(books1));
        return books;
    }
}
```

### BooksServiceTest

```
public class BookServiceStepDefinations {
    
    @Mock
    BooksRepository booksRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    BooksService booksService;
    Books book;

    @Given("^Execute Book Details$")
    public void execute_Book_Details() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        book=new Books();
    }

    @When("^I Set book request$")
    public void i_Set_book_request() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        book.setBookid(1);
        book.setBookname("A");
        book.setAuthor("A1");
        book.setPrice(100);
        List<Books>booksList=new ArrayList<Books>();
        booksList.add(book);
        Mockito.when(booksRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(booksList);
        booksService.getAllBooks();
    }

    @Then("^I receive valid Response$")
    public void i_receive_valid_Response() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        Assert.assertEquals(1, booksService.getAllBooks().size());
    }
}
```

### Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.javatpoint.BookServiceStepDefinations.i_Set_book_request(BookServiceStepDefinations.java:41)
    at ✽.When I Set book request(book.feature:5)
```

Comment: Can some one suggest me please

Comment: Start by setting a breakpoint on the line where the NPE is thrown and running it through the debugger to figure out what is null at that point that shouldn't be and figure it out from there. From the code provided I cannot see which is line 41 as the code doesn't have 41 lines.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of another one of your posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67126259/3092298 - please delete one of the questions.